# How to migrate paper_trail's whodunnit column from string to integer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paper-trail-gem

In a legacy Rails app using paper_trail, the `whodunnit` column is set to string and instead of the default `current_user.id`, this column holds the user's email. This is achieved by overriding `user_for_paper_trail` in `ApplicationController`:

```
def user_for_paper_trail
  current_user.email
end
```

Now I want to migrate to the default behavior of storing the id of the current user instead of the email.

So the approach I was thinking to take was something like this:

- add a new integer column to the `versions` table, maybe named `whodunnit_new`;
- remove `user_for_paper_trail` method in application controller and tell the models to write whodunnit info in `whodunnit_new` instead of `whodunnit`. This means, that for new versions, paper_trail is saving `id` in `whodunnit_new` and is not saving `email` in `whodunnit`;
- backfill `whodunnit_new` for old records by finding the user by email and saving thier id in the new column;
- drop the `whodunnit` column;
- rename `whodunnit_new` to `whodunnit` and remove the setting in the models for using `whodunnit_new`.

The problem is - I couldn't find a setting, which can set the name of the whodunnit column, it seems to me, that it is hard-coded. I saw that there is an alias for the `whodunnit` method (called `version_author`).

I'm using Papertrail 10 and Rails 5.2.

So my question - what should be the proper way of doing the described migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> .. I couldn't find a setting, which can set the name of the whodunnit column, it seems to me, that it is hard-coded.

Correct, the column must be named `whodunnit`. It is not configurable.

Otherwise your migration sounds good. Use a transaction and you won't need to temporarily rename the column. (Unless you're using MySQL, which has "weak" transactions, ie. not protected against DDL)